# custom option when product add to cart in magento 2.2.5

Tags: product, custom-options, addtocart, magento-2.2.5

```
<?php

namespace Ecomsolver\Measurement\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class SetAdditionalOptions implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $_request;

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Check and set information according to your need
        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add') { //checking when product is adding to cart
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            $additionalOptions = [];
            $additionalOptions[] = array(
                'label' => "Some Label",
                'value' => "good product",
            );
            $observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the above code for adding custom option when product add to cart in `magento 2.2.5` but everytime I am getting the below error:

> main.CRITICAL: Unable to unserialize value. [] []

how to fix this ?

Comment: try ditching the `serialize` call. I think this is done automatically.

Comment: try this :  

 $additionalOptions = [];
            $additionalOptions["some_label"] = array(
                'label' => "Some Label",
                'value' => "good product",
            );

Comment: how i use this code

Answer (score 0):

For Security magento  from  2.2 version, Magento suggesting to not use 
`serialize`. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/framework/serializer.html

So,**serialize()** cannot use, you have to use

> Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json

```
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serialize\Json;

...

/**
 * @var SerializerInterface
 */
proteccted $serializer;

...

public function __construct(Json $serializer) {
  $this->serializer = $serializer;
}
```

use `$this->serializer->serialize()` instead of `serialize()`.

So you have to changes

```
$observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));
```

**to**

```
$observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions));
```

Comment: not success i have update the code as you told

Comment: [2018-08-20 09:20:44] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined property: Ecomsolver\Measurement\Observer\SetAdditionalOptions::$serializer in D:\xampp\htdocs\store\app\code\Ecomsolver\Measurement\Observer\SetAdditionalOptions.php on line 36 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined property: Ecomsolver\\Measurement\\Observer\\SetAdditionalOptions::$serializer in D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\store\\app\\code\\Ecomsolver\\Measurement\\Observer\\SetAdditionalOptions.php on line 36 at D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\store\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []

Comment: getting this error after change the code

Comment: You have to do Di compile

Comment: yes i do di compile or not getting any error

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    // Check and set information according to your need
    if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add') { //checking when product is adding to cart
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $additionalOptions = array();
        if ($additionalOption = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
            $additionalOptions = (array) json_decode($additionalOption->getValue());
        }
        $additionalOptions = [];
        $additionalOptions[] = array(
            'label' => "Some Label",
            'value' => "good product",
        );
        if(count($additionalOptions) > 0) {
            $item->addOption([
                'product_id' => $item->getProductId(),
                'code' => 'additional_options',
                'value' => json_encode($additionalOptions)
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also use **checkout_cart_product_add_after** event for the above.

Comment: If it's working for you then click the green tick so that in future it helps for others.